# Difference between sequential and batch mode in the context of Naive Bayes

Tags: terminology, naive-bayes

In Neural networks, there are 2 concepts, **batch learning** and **sequential learning**.

Page 75 of ["Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective."](http://noiselab.ucsd.edu/ECE228/Murphy_Machine_Learning.pdf), Kevin Patrick Murphy uses these terms in naive Bayes:

[image]

Could someone please give more explanation the difference on sequential mode and batch mode in the context of naive Bayes?

Answer (score 1):

[Bayesian updating](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181934/sequential-update-of-bayesian) can be done all-at-once, or sequentially. What this means is that you can apply Bayes theorem to the data updating the prior to posterior one sample at a time, so you take sample $x_1$, use Bayes theorem to get posterior given this sample, use this posterior as a prior for sample $x_2$, etc. Under some mild assumptions, this would be equivalent to looking at all the data and it’s joint likelihood to update the prior.

Batch mode means the all-at-once update, or part-of-data-at-once approach, as compared to sequential.