# Bayesian inference on sequential data

Tags: time-series, bayesian

I have a dataset that is potentially contaminated. The variable of interest is continuous (non-Gaussian but for simplicity sake let's just assume that it is). Let's say our prior is that the true mean should be 50% of the in-sample mean but we don't know for sure. As we observe more out-of-sample observations, it either confirms or rejects our prior assumption. For example, 1 out-of-sample observation isn't enough evidence to move away from the prior (in-sample x 50%) but let's say 50 out-of-sample observations are plenty to give a reasonable assessment as to whether the prior is right or wrong. I'm interested in the true out-of-sample mean. What's tricky about this problem (at least to me) is the need for sequential update. What would be a good approach to this problem?

I've already found this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/490657/sequential-updating-in-bayesian-inference-pymc3) that doesn't really have an answer.

[Edit] One option I've thought about is to assume Gaussian likelihood and prior. The assumed prior is the in-sample mean and precision, but the mean is adjusted by the assumed overstatement. Let prior be $N(\mu_0, \pi_0)$, where $\pi = 1/\sigma^2$ is precision. The posterior is:

$$
\mu_{post}=\frac{\pi_0\mu_0}{\pi_0+\pi}+\frac{\pi x}{\pi_0+\pi} \\
\pi_{post}=\pi_0+\pi
$$

I don't know what the precision of each new observation is but I thought a reasonable assumption is to just assume it has the same precision as the in-sample data. This means that the first update my precision doubled, while mean is the average between my prior and the first observation. Then assume my posterior is my new prior for the next update. However, this seems to be adjusting too aggressively to each new observation, particularly at the beginning when I have only a few out-of-sample observations. What I'm expecting to see if at the beginning, my posterior is barely different from my prior, but adjusting closer to the observed out-of-sample data over time.

Comment: Could you tell us more about what exactly your data is? The abstract example doesn't tell much about what exactly is the problem. Why sequential updating does matter here? As noticed in the linked answer, sequential vs non-sequential Bayesian updating lead to *the same* result, so it seems like you won't something else than just a sequential update.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. A close analogy to the data is monthly foot traffic at a shopping mall for the past 10 years. The data is expensive to collect so we can't just throw it out and start again, but we suspect the data in the past has been overstated. Variance is high relative to the mean so with just a few out-of-sample observations, it's hard to tell whether the mean is indeed biased. The sequential nature is important because we need to act on the best estimate of population mean every month, when I only have a few out-of-sample observations.

Comment: I've added a bit more on what I'm thinking in the question.

Comment: I'm lost. This sounds like standard Bayesian updating, isn't it?

Comment: I guess it's how aggressive the update is. So going by my example, if I assume each new obs to have the same precision, my first update is an average between my prior and the first obs. This is too aggressive. I would have expected the transition to be much slower (my posterior should barely move from my prior if given only a few obs). I guess that means I pick a much lower precision for each new obs but what should that value be?

Comment: So you basically want to use higher weights for new vs old data? Why is that?

Comment: Because standard deviation is quite high compared to the magnitude of the mean. If I use the standard Bayesian update, the posterior jumps all over the place at the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a framework that might be applicable.

There are two related *entities*. There are $T_i$ observations for entity: $Y_i = (y_{i1}, \ldots, y_{iT_i})$ for $i \in \{1,2\}$. Each of the two entities depends on an unknown parameter $\mu_i$: $p(Y_i|\mu_i)$. If the observations for entity $i$ were iid (independent and identically distributed) then
\begin{equation}
p(Y_i|\mu_i) = \prod_{t=1}^{T_i} p(y_{it}|\mu_i) . 
\end{equation}

Given this setup, the only possible connection between $\mu_2$ and $Y_1$ (for example) is through the joint prior for $(\mu_1,\mu_2)$. In other words, we can learn about $\mu_2$ from $Y_1$ if we believe that we can learn about $\mu_2$ from $\mu_1$. We can complete the connection in two steps. First,
\begin{equation}
p(\mu_2|Y_1,\mu_1) = \frac{p(Y_2|\mu_2)\,p(\mu_2|\mu_1)}{p(Y_2|\mu_1)} .
\end{equation}
Second, given $p(\mu_1|Y_1)$ we have
\begin{equation}
p(\mu_2|Y_1,Y_2) = \int p(\mu_1|Y_2,\mu_1)\,p(\mu_1|Y_1)\,d\mu_1 . 
\end{equation}

We can arrive at the same place via a different route. First compute
\begin{equation}
p(\mu_2|Y_1) = \int p(\mu_2|\mu_1)\,p(\mu_1|Y_1)\,d\mu_1 
\end{equation}
and second
\begin{equation}
p(\mu_2|Y_1,Y_2) = \frac{p(Y_2|\mu_2)\,p(\mu_2|Y_1)}{p(Y_2|Y_1)} .
\end{equation}
(Note that the sample information $Y_2$ is contained in the likelihood and the non-sample information $Y_1$ is contained in the prior.)

Either way, you would need to come up with $p(\mu_2|\mu_1)$, the distribution for $\mu_2$ if you knew $\mu_1$, and $p(\mu_1|Y_1)$, which is what you know about $\mu_1$ from its own dataset.

#### Updating

Suppose we get an additional observation for entity 2 so that $Y_2' = (Y_2, y_2')$. Then
\begin{equation}
p(\mu_2|Y_1,Y_2') = \frac{p(y_2'|\mu_2)\,p(\mu_2|Y_1,Y_2)}{p(y_2|Y_1,Y_2)} .
\end{equation}

#### Nuisance parameters.

If there are nuisance parameters, they can be integrated out. For example,
\begin{equation}
p(Y_i|\mu_i) = \int p(Y_i|\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)\,p(\sigma_i^2|\mu_i)\,d\sigma_i^2 .
\end{equation}
To flesh this example out a bit, suppose
\begin{equation}
p(Y_i|\mu_i,\sigma_i) = \prod_{t=1}^{T_i} \textsf{N}(y_{it}|\mu_i,\sigma_i^2) 
\end{equation}
and $p(\sigma_i^2|\mu_i) = \textsf{Inv-Gamma}(\sigma_i^2|a,b)$.
In this case,
\begin{equation}
p(Y_i|\mu_i) \propto \textsf{Student}(\mu_i|m_i,s_i^2,\nu_i) ,
\end{equation}
where $(m_i,s_i^2,\nu_i)$ depend on $Y_i$ [and $(a,b)$].

#### Hyperparameters.

Sometimes it is convenient to express the prior via hyperparameters. In particular, suppose $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are conditionally independent, conditional on the hyperparameter $\phi$:
\begin{equation}
p(\mu_1,\mu_2|\phi) = p(\mu_1|\phi)\,p(\mu_2|\phi) . 
\end{equation}
The dependence between $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ follows from the joint variation due to $\phi$:
\begin{equation}
p(\mu_1,\mu_2) = \int p(\mu_1|\phi)\,p(\mu_2|\phi)\,p(\phi)\,d\phi . 
\end{equation}
(The symmetric prior implied by the use of the hyperparameter may not be appropriate for your problem.)

Having introduced the hyperparameter, it may be convenient to delay integrating it out until a later stage of the analysis. Note that the joint posterior distribution can be expressed as
\begin{equation}
p(\mu_1,\mu_2,\phi|Y_1,Y_2) \propto p(Y_1|\mu_1)\,p(Y_2|\mu_2)\,p(\mu_1|\phi)\,p(\mu_2|\phi)\, p(\phi).
\end{equation}
A Gibbs sampler could be based on the complete set of full conditional posterior distributions:
\begin{align}
p(\mu_1|Y_1,\phi) &\propto p(Y_1|\mu_1)\,p(\mu_1|\phi) \\
p(\mu_2|Y_2,\phi) &\propto p(Y_2|\mu_2)\,p(\mu_2|\phi) \\
p(\phi|\mu_1,\mu_2) &\propto p(\mu_1|\phi)\,p(\mu_2|\phi)\,p(\phi) .
\end{align}
There is a sense in which the hyperparameter is the carrier of information between the entities.

Note that $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are treated symmetrically here. In addition to learning about $\mu_2$ from $Y_1$, we also learn about $\mu_1$ from $Y_2$.

Comment: Thanks very much for the comprehensive answer. How would this be used in an online context? I'm familiar with the Gibbs sampler etc. but I need to update my posterior (which becomes my prior) for each new observation.

Comment: @stevew I've added a brief section on updating, assuming the new observation is for entity 2 (i.e., the new regime). I should note that I am only providing a conceptual framework for thinking about how to link what is learned from the first entity to the second. The actual way that one would apply this framework (the computations involved) will depend on the specifics of the problem. For some settings it may be straightforward to apply this framework and for others it may be quite difficult.