# Sequential Bayesian Update - Weight for Prior n-size?

Tags: bayesian, posterior

*(Sorry if this is answered elsewhere, but I can't seem to find.)*

Something about Bayesian updates that has always confused me - does the "current" posterior n-size matter? And if so, why not?

For instance, according to [this](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/%7Esteffen/teaching/bs2HT9/kalman.pdf) (page 3), we have

$$
\tilde\pi_{n+1}(\theta) \propto \pi_{n}(\theta)f(x_{n+1}|\boldsymbol{x_n},\theta)
$$

Seems to me, $n$ could be 10 or 10,000, and the "impact" of $x_{n+1}$ on $\pi$ would be the same.  Shouldn't we give the "existing posterior" greater weight if there are more "existing" observations?

I'm sure I'm missing something, but can't seem to put my finger on it.

Comment: What do you mean by *current" posterior n-size*? Care to clarify?

Comment: If $n$ is larger, $\pi_n(\theta)$ is likely to be a narrower distribution, which may correspond to your idea of "greater weight"

Comment: I mean you have seen n observations ("current") and want to update based on the n+1 observation.  Where in the math does it account for the magnitude of n?

Comment: @Henry is that true? Why does size of n have to do with the shape of the distribution?

Comment: @dashnick Try an example yourself, for example a  Bernoulli (or binomial) likelihood and a Beta prior and posterior distribution

Comment: @Henry makes sense.. so it's sort of implicitly embedded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The point of Bayesian sequential updating](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181934/sequential-update-of-bayesian) is that no mater if you update prior with likelihood over all of your data at once, or if you do this sequentially, the result would be the same. This wouldn't hold if different observations had different weights. If for some reason you need to assign different weights to different samples (e.g. survey weights), that this would work the same in sequential and all-at-once updating. However if you don't have good reason for doing so, usually you do not want different samples to affect the result to different degree.