# allocating degree belief to forecast value

Tags: bayesian, forecasting, bayes, ensemble-learning

We have a number of providers for a forecast of wind power generation per country per date.

Values are forecast up to one week ahead.

Forecasts may be compared with actual values of reported wind power generation for a particular date.

The error decreases as the forecast time distance decreases.

I would like to construct a simple model which will give me a level of belief allocated to each of the providers based on their forecast (and the history of their forecasts).

I am a Bayesian newbie, reading though Kruschke's excellent book, and thought that a linear regression where $x_{i}$ are the forecasts and $y$ is the actual would be appropriate - do you agree? Any tips for formulating this General Linear Model?

The previous forecast performance would give a distribution of error for each provider, which could be used as the prior?
Then when new information is received, in this case a new forecast for a specific number of days ahead, we could update the overall probability of the forecast out-turn by considering all the ensemble probabilities. Is this a reasonable approach?

Comment: Does each of the providers make single or multiple forecasts (e.g. you have $i$-th providers' forecast for $j$-th turbine $x_{ij}$ with multiple values per turbine and per provider)?

Comment: single forecasts. i'm looking at forecast per country at the moment

Comment: Could you provide data-example for your question?

Comment: not really as this data is on licence from providers. i will try and add more detail to the question

Comment: You want to create one forecast from many forecasts of different providers?

Comment: @user31264 yes that is correct, dynamically adjusting how the forecast is construct as time progresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have several $x_{ij}$ forecasts ($j$-th providers forecast for the $y_i$ value) and want to combine them, then you are thinking about using some kind of [weighted mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean) of them (see here for [examples](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155817/combining-probabilities-information-from-different-sources/188554#188554)), e.g.

$$ y_i = \sum_j w_j x_{ij} $$

where $w_j$ are weights such that $\sum_j w_j = 1$. Weights $w_j$ in this case can be interpreted as $j$-th providers reliability.

Your model seems to be more complicated than this since you also want to include information about forecasts time distance $t_j$. First you need to notice that you are not interested in actual $y_i$'s but rather in providers errors. For this, let's define variable $z_{ij} = y_i - x_{ij}$, for difference between actual value of $y_i$ and prediction of $j$-th provider. Such difference depends on providers reliability $\alpha_j$ and the forecast delay $t_{ij}$, i.e.

$$ z_{ij} = \alpha_j + \beta t_{ij} + \varepsilon_{ij} $$

$\alpha_j$ is a random variable with mean $\bar \alpha_j$ (additive bias), and variance $\sigma_{\alpha_j}^2$ (how much forecasts by $j$-th provider vary in their error). In this particular case I assumed that the effect of delay $\beta$ is the same for all providers, but you can make different assumptions. Knowing values of those parameters you would be able to predict given the data the expected error for $j$-th provider that made his forecast delayed by $t_{ij}$ time points. You can use such bias estimates for bias correction for individual forecasts: $\hat y_i  = x_{ij} + \hat z_{ij}$.

The absolute value of inverted estimated error $|\hat z_{ij}^{-1}|$ could instead of bias correction be used to weight different forecasts and make weighted forecast

$$ \hat y_i = \frac{\sum_j |\hat z_{ij}^{-1}| x_{ij}}{ \sum_j{|\hat z_{ij}^{-1}|}} $$

Since each combined forecast is weighted by expected, inverted error (the more biased it is, the less weight it has), you [could expect](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147881/more-statistical-way-to-average-n-predictions?lq=1) such forecast to be (on average) better than individual forecasts.

In Bayesian setting you can set up some priors on $\alpha_j$ and $\beta$ to estimate them and then, in sequential analysis, when new data arrives use their posterior estimates as priors for new estimation (check [Bayesian updating](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169144/bayesian-updating-point-for-point)).